# How to upgrade the deprecated Neo4J lucene indexes?

Tags: neo4j, lucene

I upgraded from 3.3.9 to 3.5.17 version of Neo4J and when launched it says:

```
Deprecated index providers in use: lucene-1.0 (9 indexes). Use procedure 'db.indexes()' to see what indexes use which index provider.
```

Then when I run that command it lists the 9 indexes that look something like:

```
| "INDEX ON :Concept(name)"   | "Unnamed index" | ["Concept"]   | ["name"]      | "ONLINE" | "node_label_property" | 100.0    | {version: "1.0", key: "lucene"} | 3  | ""
```

The question is: how to upgrade them? These were made for searches, so should I delete them? Or what is the way it's going to work in the new version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the old indexes or delete them and create the new ones.

For each index you can do the following:

1. Delete each of them:

```
DROP INDEX ON :Concept(name);
```

2. Create a new (native) one:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Concept(name);
```

3. Verify they have been created:

```
CALL db.indexes();
```

(this will show the progress)

Note, that native indexes sometimes might have limitations on the length of each parameter (4096 max length). In that case the index won't be created and you'll see an error at step 3.

In that case you can simply make a search on the property of the type you had an error on, using the `SIZE(node.property)` to filter the results. And then change that parameter and (optionally) add a constraint on it to avoid this in the future.

Comment: I had to run the following query to find the properties that are too long: `match (c) where SIZE(c.name) > 4000